# Filter on DBSet, DBSet.AsQueryable() or DBSet.AsQueryable<T>()

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Should you add filtering (and e.g. ordering) to the DBSet object or first call DBSet.AsQueryable() or  DBSet.AsQueryable()?

In which case do you need to use the next functions?

```
Context.Set<T>().Where<>
Context.Set<T>().AsQueryable<T>().Where<>
Context.Set<T>().AsQueryable().Where<>
```

Comment: `DbSet<T>` implements `IQueryable<T>` so `AsQueryable()` serves no purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to call `IQueryable` because `DBSet<T>` result is already returning as queryable.

For example this:

```cs
Context.Set<MyTable>.Where(i => i.itemId == 1) // returns IQueryable<MyTable>
```

will return a list of `IQueryable` results.